# How can I figure out what a beer tastes like based on the name (i.e. before ordering/trying it)?

Tags: taste, flavor, terminology

I am a relative newbie in terms of drinking... I don't know too much about different types of beers (or different types of other alcohols). I only drink occasionally, so when I find something I like, I stick with it - which means I've mostly avoided this problem until now. But I want to branch out from what I know so that I can try new things and learn more.

Say I'm at a bar, and looking at their drinks menu or seeing what's on tap. Assuming there are names listed for the beers, but not descriptions of their flavor/taste, how can I figure out what a beer tastes like before ordering/trying it?

I know that many IPAs are bitter (which I'm not a fan of), and I know that the wheat beers I've had are generally less bitter (which I like more)... But I don't know too much about different kinds of beer (or why they taste the way they taste) besides that. I'm interested in learning more.

Answer (score 4):

One good resource is [BeerAdvocate](https://www.beeradvocate.com). [Untappd](https://untappd.com) is another, but you need to create an account for that site. BeerAdvocate has a whole section on [beer styles](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/top-styles/) along with reviews and ratings of specific beers. In particular you might like [saisons](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/129/) or [farmhouse ales](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/127/). Look for the IBU listing on the beer review. IBU's below 30 are probably more to your liking if you don't like bitterness.

Comment: You can also take a look at the BJCP : https://dev.bjcp.org/style/2015/beer/ They a lots of type of beer and what they should look like.

Comment: @f222 Thanks, I wasn’t aware of that site.   Perhaps you could post that as an answer.

Comment: I second this suggestion. Personally, I love Untapped and you can view metrics about which beers you rated more highly (the bonus of having to log in is that it keeps track!)

Answer (score 4):

**How can I figure out what a beer tastes like based on the name (i.e. before ordering/trying it)?**

The short answer is **no**.

Personal experience tells me that it is not possible to figure out how a beer will taste like without trying it first.

For example, I have tried some chocolate beers. Some have notes of that I consider powdered cocoa chocolate, while others will have a taste somewhat closer to milk chocolate. Look are deceiving here.

Some liquor stores where I live will graciously let you buy one bottle or can to try out in order to be able to see if you like the beer or not.

Comment: While I agree in some respects, knowing the style of beer gives you some idea of taste. If I order a porter, I roughly know what it will taste like. Not however if it is a good porter or bad. I don't order sour beers because I know I won't like them.

Comment: @EricS This is quite true. I admit that as being so.

Comment: @EricS: Yep, that's pretty much what I'm hoping to learn - not necessarily whether a particular beer is good, but at least the general kind of taste/what to expect based on the style of beer.